# Excel: search if a specific keyword exists in a column

Tags: excel, excel-automation, search-keywords

I was wondering if anyone out there can help to resolve the issue I am facing right now, actually I wanted to ask that I have 1 column with 5k + rows, and each row has a statement in it and if I search for a keyword , how come I can find out that keyword from the entire column ,and wherever that keyword is occurring, it should mention yes or no or 1 or 0 in front of that row  because I can not do it manually for all rows? thanks in anticipation and looking forward to your quick response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `IF` and `SEARCH` together to flag the rows that have "Hi" in them for example. I hope this helps.

```
=IFERROR(IF(SEARCH("Hi",A1,1)>0,1,0),0)
```

[image]

Comment: No problem @MuneebHassan , please accept as answer and upvote if helpful.